# Delete last 5 characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to delete the last 5 characters from the string?

```
procedure TForm1.Button15Click(Sender: TObject);
var
str:string;
begin
str:='012345678911234567892223456789';
showmessage(str);
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The absolute easiest way, with the least amount of overhead:

```
str := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
ShowMessage(str);
SetLength(str, Length(str) - 5);
ShowMessage(str);
```

This involves no allocation of a temporary string, no access to anything in the RTL that wastes CPU time, and is extremely fast and efficient.

Comment: Copy, say, doesn't allocate a temporary string. It makes a new string, and copies the content. SetLength is a re-allocation. Which may, or may not, involve a copy. That's up to the memory manager. I think it is true though that SetLength is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Using stringhelper routines (not available in D7 though):

```
ShowMessage(str.Substring(0,str.Length-5));
```

In D7 using the StrUtils unit:

```
ShowMessage(LeftStr(str,Length(str)-5));
```

Comment: Nitpick: That doesn't delete the last 5 characters. It only shows a substring, but does nothing to change the string itself. The question asks about deleting the last 5 chars. (Not voting either way; just pointing it out.)

Comment: @KenWhite, I will leave that to the interested reader to figure out. Anyway, the given example was to present a shorter string within ShowMessage, so I guess I followed the intention in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
str:= copy (str, 1, length (str) - 5)
```

Another would be

```
delete (str, length (str) - 4, 5)
```

Comment: Oke thanks  something like that Delete(str, Length(Str)-4, 5);

Comment: Using `delete(str:string, index: integer; count: integer)` the deletion starts at str[index]. Length(str)-4 would be correct for index.